# Pointing eclipse to JRE 1.7 instead of 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, java-6

I am getting error whenever I click eclipse icon that version 1.6 of the jvm is not suitable for this product. Version 1.7 or greater is required.

My other java applications in the system are using JRE 1.6 so I dont want to change that.

I have JDK 7 in my system as well but how can I point my eclipse to JDK 1.7 instead of default 1.6.

Thanks

Comment: set JAVA_HOME to JDK 7 path.

Comment: Use eclipse.ini... https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Comment: Right click on project go to build path and remove 1.6, add new system library and select new Jdk there.

Comment: You should probably upgrade to Java 8, both 6 and 7 are end of life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options.

Since you want to default to Java 1.6 for most of your other applications, I'd suggest modifying your Eclipse.ini:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

EXAMPLE:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```